# javascript: what is the difference between channels and observables

Tags: javascript, channel, observable, event-stream

What is the difference between channels (https://github.com/ubolonton/js-csp) and observables (https://rpominov.github.io/kefir/)? Are there specific use cases where using one would make more sense than using the other?

Comment: You can push to a channel, but not to an observable. You might want to have a look [at this](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor/) and [over here](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor/issues/20)

Comment: does this have any implications if i only want to use them as stream of events?

Comment: Yes, how these events are generated is looking different. Consuming a stream of events works pretty much the same.